# what happens when routine "free" fails in a "try" block in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, free

Typically, if memory issue occurred in calling routine "free", a program will stop immediately with error message telling details of the error. Now assume "free" is called in a "try" block. If an error occurred with the call, will the program stop immediately with an error message, or will the program completes execution of the "try" block before exiting with error message?

Comment: `free` is a C function, it doesn't throw C++ exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` can't error out without some preexisting problem in your code occurring, almost certainly a result of undefined behavior. Once you're in the land of nasal demons, there are no guarantees. `free` doesn't have a concept of exceptions (it's a C function, no C++ features), or even error return codes; if you corrupt your heap, the program is already screwed, and what comes next can be anything. In practice, I'd expect one of four possibilities:

1. `free` doesn't notice the corrupted heap, and just makes things worse silently (`try` block continues running, because it doesn't realize anything is wrong)
2. `free` notices the corrupted heap, and the program dies immediately (no `try`/`catch` handling)
3. `free` is operating on a pointer to an invalid/unallocated region of memory, and you die with a segfault, bus error, etc. (again, no `try`/`catch` handling)
4. The pointer is to allocated memory that's not part of the heap; behaves like #1 or #2 depending on how "heap-like" it happens to look to the code.

Comment: Addition to the 3rd situation: on Windows a SEH exception can be thrown by OS and caught with a corresponding `catch(...)` block. To be more accurate: a program must be compiled with a specific option to make `catch(...)` block to be able to catch SEH exceptions.

Comment: If "free" doesn't notice the corrupted heap, will the corruption be detected by the end of the execution? Can heap corruption happen without notification in a program?

Comment: @ZiqiFan: It's undefined behavior. The answer is "maybe". The answer to just about any situation involving undefined behavior is "???". Heap corruption definitely *can* happen without being noticed, but that's no guarantee it'll be consistent (Windows has changed the runtime allocator in ways that cause a program that "worked" on an earlier version of Windows to die in later versions; sometimes they've put in compatibility hacks to make popular programs use the old allocator just to keep them "working" despite the bad code).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Is there a way to systematically debug heap corruption in a large code base in linux?

Comment: @ZiqiFan: Typically the first step is [using `valgrind`'s `memcheck` tool](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html), which diagnoses a whole host of memory misuse issues.

Comment: @ShadowRanger valgrind is really useful. I found the line that caused the heap corruption immediately using the tool. Thanks!